# call log function in windows phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, voip

I am developing VoIP application (Dialler) in windows phone 8, In that application contain  dial pad , contacts, call log , I already create a dial pad and contact list, I need to develop a call log function  in that application. I struggle in to create a call log for windows phone 8 any help please

Answer (score 0):

This is a class that creates an XML file which holds the logs of all calls. You didn't specify the question enough or what you want to do, or what have you already tried. So here is an idea of what you should implement:

```
public class Logger
{
private static string logPath;
public Logger()
{
    logPath = "/Logs/log.xml";
}

public void LogData(string contactName, string duration)
{
    Object thisLock = new Object();
    logPath += DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace('.', '_') + ".log";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    lock (thisLock)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlNode root = null;

            if (File.Exists(logPath))
            {
                doc.Load(logPath);
                root = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Call");
            }
            else
            {
                doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null));
                root = doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Call"));
            }

            XmlElement call = doc.CreateElement("call");
            root.AppendChild(call);

            XmlElement xcontactName = doc.CreateElement("contactName");
            xcontactName.InnerText = contactName;
            call.AppendChild(xcontactName);

            XmlElement xdate = doc.CreateElement("date");
            xdate.InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            call.AppendChild(xdate);

            XmlElement xduration = doc.CreateElement("duration");
            xduration.InnerText = duration;
            call.AppendChild(xduration);

            doc.Save(logPath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```